# React Native: Move component in view hierarchy

Tags: react-native

How can a component be moved from one part of the render hierarchy to another while maintaining component state? In the example below, the result of the call to setView creates a new view (as seen by a new `instanceValue` number), even though I pass what looks like the existing view.

```
class TestTo extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      instanceValue: parseInt(Math.random() * 100)
    }
  }

  render() {
    return <Text>{this.state.instanceValue}</Text>
  }
}

class TestFrom extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      view: <TestTo />
    }
  }

  doSet = () => {
    this.props.nav.setView(this.state.view);
  }

  render() {
    return <View>
      <Button title="doaction" onPress={this.doSet} />
      {this.state.view}
    </View>
  }
}

class Holder extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      view: <TestFrom nav={this} />
    }
  }

  setView = (view) => {
    this.setState({view: view});
  }

  render() {
    return this.state.view
  }
}

<Holder />
```

Comment: Why is it important that it is the same view? If you render another view with the same state and props as the original view the result would be the same, or am I missing something?

Comment: I'm working on seamless animations of components between logical screens. This example comes from an exploration of handing off views instead of rebuilding them. I'm open if the approach is wrong.

Comment: Okay! Just a thought: it may be because of the setState() call. You could  maybe try dropping setState() and manually forcing the re-render with forceUpdate()?

Comment: did you ever find a way to do this? i'm trying to move a component from one view hierarchy to another which i can achieve using react-native-portals but the problem is that component state doesn't transfer over.. if achievable there has to be some kind of react-native function that will hold and transfer the native UIView for you.

Comment: I've been away from the react world for a while, but any portal implementation isn't really helpful if the state doesn't go with it. Maybe run their example and see if you're seeing the same behavior, then I'd walk their code to see what gives.